# Extract values within mean+1SD and mean-1SD in R

Tags: r

I would like to extract values falling within mean-1SD and mean+1SD, mean-2SD and mean+2SD from a data frame 'data' and in sum the values from extractions should be equal to the final sample size, but my following code do not give me correct values.

Any suggestions?

```
within1sd <- data[!(data$values < mean-SD & data$values > mean ), ]


within1sd <- data[!(data$values < mean-SD & data$values > mean ), ]
```

Comment: `mean` and `sd` are functions.  You need to apply on the columns i.e. `mean(data$values)` and `sd(data$values)`

Answer (score 3):

as @akrun says, you need to call/evaluate the `mean` and `sd` functions to get the mean and standard deviation, then you can use them to get the values you're after

something like:

```
mu <- mean(data$values)
sigma <- sd(data$values)
data[abs(data$values - mu) < sigma,]
```

you could of course put all this on one line, but thought this was easier to read